# CodePen: How to swap these blocks in this specific order, in responsive?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

Consider these 4 blocks.

[image]

In HTML, they are ordered like that: first, the division corresponding to the red block, then the orange one, then the yellow and finally the green.

In responsive, each of these blocks are `width: 100%`, thus they are shown in this same order.

However, I would want to display the blocks like that, in responsive: red, orange, **green, yellow**, etc.

How could I deal with this problem using only CSS? I can make use of flex boxing layout.

```css
#parent {
  width: 1400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

#div_1, #div_2, #div_3, #div_4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div_1 {
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
}

#div_2 {
  background: orange;
}

#div_3 {
  background: yellow;
}

#div_4 {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #div_1, #div_2, #div_3, #div_4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div id="div_1"></div><!--
  --><div id="div_2"></div>

  <div id="div_3"></div><!--
  --><div id="div_4"></div>

</div>
```

**Here is the CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPvyKZ**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

possible with `flexbox` and `order`

```css
#parent {
  width: 1400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display:flex; /* display:flex for use 'order' . */
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:center;
}

#div_1, #div_2, #div_3, #div_4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div_1 {
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
  order:1; /* red is first */
}

#div_2 {
  background: orange;
  order:2; /* orange is second */
}

#div_3 {
  background: yellow;
  order:4; /* yellow is fourth */
}

#div_4 {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px;
  order:3; /* green is third */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #div_1, #div_2, #div_3, #div_4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div id="div_1"></div><!--
  --><div id="div_2"></div>

  <div id="div_3"></div><!--
  --><div id="div_4"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your media query:

```
  #div_3, #div_4 {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
```